# Angular 6 Show template from child in parent component

Tags: angular

For an Angular 6 application I want to clean up my code and generalize some parts.

On a detail page in my application is have two main sections a summary and some more detailed stuff. The summary is split up in three mat-cards. And the detailed part is a larger mat-card over the whole width of the page. The summary part is for each type of detail page more or less the same. The detailed page is for each type different.

I want to create an overview component, this component handles all the logic (HTTP-calls, etc.). For the detailed section i want to create a custom component for each type, these components will handle the visualization (different charts, tables, etc.). Till now no big problem.

The problem I stubbled upon is that in one of the detail mat-cards there is custom visualisation specific for each type. So now my question, is it possible to somehow show content from a child component into the parent. I attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTc3v.png) to clarify my situation.

Comment: this can be a good read on "input" and "output": https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/

Comment: Thanks, but I was more looking into: Angular ng-template, ng-container and ngTemplateOutlet. My idea was to define in the custom component a template (For ex. detail-template) and include that template into the parent component.

Comment: @SanderVerkaemer did you find a way to do that? I'm asking about the same thing, however, I have a way to do it but I want a better method check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67871409/ngtemplateoutlet-template-binding-between-components

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ng-content`: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

In your parent, you would include `ng-content` blocks with selectors that your child component would place content into.