# Angular - Project content from child component to parent component

Tags: angular

I know I can use `<ng-content>` to project/transclude content from parent to child component but I want the opposite:

I have a main component with a kind of statusbar on top of it and I use routing (`<router-outlet>`) to display the current page.

I want each page to be able to define elements into the statusbar of the main component.

Here's a partial answer about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53209994/11008903 but it does'nt work, even if I directly include my child component without routing (`<my-child-component>` instead of `<router-outlet>`). I can't find any way to do it.

I join an [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RHGh.png) of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using a named `router-outlet` in order to achieve the required functionality. This way, you could have another `router-outlet` replacing the "some buttons and text" part in your illustration, and via named routing you could present different components within that navigation area. You may refer to this article for multi dimensional routing:

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/

Comment: Thanks for this solution but making two component (one for the actual page and one for the status content) is not a maintenable solution. If I don't find another way I think I'm just going to include the statusbar in the page component directly.